# Здравствуйте, при использовании pyinstaller выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, telebot, pyinstaller, exe

"""

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 20, in 
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

"""

Весь код: https://pastebin.com/wuxySNt4

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить библиотеку

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```